# How to make required field validator on dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a dropdownlist where I added an extra value to (Choose channel...). If this value is selected I want a message displayed that is required, what I tried is:

```
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ServiceChannelDropDownList" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID">
   <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="Choose channel..." />
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DropDownListRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="ServiceChannelDropDownList" 
                                InitialValue="-1"
                                ErrorMessage="*"                                 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

Unfortunately this just let me select the initial value (which naturally does not exist in the database) without saying it is not allowed. How to solve this?

Comment: How you bind the database values to Dropdown in code behind? You need to add the default item there

Comment: The problem is I cannot add an item there since the Primary key is generated automatically and cannot be set to a specific value. Or should I check serverside on the -1 value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the default value in your code behind(.cs) where you bind Dropdownlist data, instead of doing it in .aspx page

```
ServiceChannelDropDownList.DataBind();
ServiceChannelDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose channel...","-1"));
```

Comment: It still does not display a message. Binding serverside or client side does not make a difference.

Comment: @user2609980, Can you add your server side code tried?

Comment: I added the solution. No server side code necessary. I needed to implement a Validationgroup to the requiredfieldvalidator.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ServiceChannelDropDownList" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
    runat="server" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="ID">
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Choose channel..." />
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DropDownListRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="ServiceChannelDropDownList" 
                                InitialValue="0"
                                ErrorMessage="*"                                 
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</td>
```

Comment: That is what I have now? :-)

Comment: You have taken value -1 of choose channel and I have taken 0. please look code posted by me again

Comment: Thanks. I see, I tried this and that does not make a difference.

Comment: Try java-script validation for it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a ValidationGroup to the RequiredFieldValidator, e.g.,

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DropDownListRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="ServiceChannelDropDownList"
                            InitialValue="0"
                            ErrorMessage="Channel is required."
                            ValidationGroup="WorkflowValidation" 
                            CssClass="ValidationCss" 
                            EnableTheming="false">*
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Thanks all for the help!